Obtaining Elements in Linked Lists in Lean4
I am currently working on a proof involving chains in partially ordered sets in Lean right now, and am facing some issues regarding obtaining an element from a chain of arbitrary length (e.g. given a chain x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_n I want an element like x_5 where 5 < n). Currently, this is what I have:
import Mathlib.Data.Fintype.Basic
import Mathlib.Data.PNat.Defs

variable {P : Type*} [PartialOrder P] [Fintype P]

abbrev chain (L : List P) : Prop := List.Chain' (· < ·) L

def lex {P : Type*} [PartialOrder P] (L : List P) (r : ℕ+) (h : chain L) (h₁ : L.length = r) := L[(k : Fin r)] 

where P is a partially ordered set. I've tried using the .get function but Lean returns a type mismatch error. I'm still fairly new to Lean so any help/advice is appreciated, thanks!

I’m struggling to understand your question.  Are you just looking to get the nth element of a Lean list (and the partially ordered stuff is just a side comment on your motivation).  If so, I might mark this question as a duplicate.

Does this answer your question? Getting an element of a list in Lean

If that doesn’t answer your question, then please provide more clarity, including a minimal working example which produces the sort of error you are getting.

I see you edited your question, and the code you provide works fine. Did you figure it out?

Also you can shorten three of the arguments to just (k : Fin (L.length)) (and then put the body as L[k]).  (And less importantly your first two arguments about P are already covered by the variables above it.). But otherwise good job!

Hi, there were still some issues after I edited my question, but I've managed to sort them out since then, thanks for the reply and the advice!
